# Partition aware hazelcast queue

Tags: java, queue, hazelcast

Is there anyway we can perform a partition aware operation on Hazelcast distributed queue?

So for example, I would have multiple consumer nodes on a queue, and would expect 'similar' type of messages to be processed by the same node everytime. By similar type, I mean some business key for the message.

Currently we are having a distributed streaming data processing ecosystem, by consuming messages from local entry listener on a IMap. A particular object model property is set as the key, so we know the models are distributed in partitions key wise. The processing logic can thus be executed locally and without using a distributed lock (or any lock at all as per design contract). I would expect the similar behaviour using a distributed blocking queue instead.

Is that feasible? Using Hazelcast 3.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the queue (currently) is not a partitioned data-structure? So there is a single member in the cluster responsible for storing all data in that queue (and another member for the backup).

You can control where a queue is stored, e.g. if you have 2 queues and want them to be stored in the same partition, use

foo@somekey
bar@somekey

In this case both queues are stored in the 'somekey' partition.

Comment: No I wasn't aware that queue isn't a partitioned data structure. Well, how do we achieve 'distributed' then? Looking at QueueStore interface, somehow I deduced that a queue is built on top of an IMap, with key as some unique id and value with the object being offered. Can you please throw some more detail on how this is implemented? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: A partitioned queue is on the road map, but it isn't going to be added in the next Hazelcast release (3.5.. expected somewhere in April/March 2015). So perhaps the September 2015.

In Hazelcast 2.x the IQueue as based on the IMap, with Hazelcast 3.5 it isn't. Have you looked at the ITopic? You can create a pub/sub solution and you can use this for streaming.  You can also have a look at our SPI; the lower level infrastructure. It isn't that complicated to create your own distributed data-structures.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/spi